# Anchor link to every product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use WooCommerce on WordPress. Now when I click (open) some product I have to scroll down lot, because there is long header and menu before product itself.

So, my question is: How to add anchor to product link when I click (open) it?

If you don't understand, please ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_loop_product_link` filter to modify the archive product urls.

```
// Add to (child) theme functions.php
function my_prefix_modify_woocommerce_loop_product_link( $url, $product ) {
  /**
    * Adds the id of the product wrap element from single product view
    * as an anchor parameter to the WooC archive loop product url
    * e.g. http://www.mystore.com/my-product#single-produt-wrap-id
    * update "single-produt-wrap-id" to match your setup
    */
  return $url . "#single-produt-wrap-id";
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', 'my_prefix_modify_woocommerce_loop_product_link', 10, 2 );
```